# Деление двух чисел

Tags: javascript

Есть два input'а, я хочу ввести туда числа и в третьем получить результат деления.
Где ошибка? Результат не выводится.

```js
function calc1() {
  var gold1, dps1, res1
  gold1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("gold1").value);
  dps1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("dps1").value);
  res1 = gold1*dps1; 
  document.getElementById("res1").value = res1;
}
```

```html
<input id="gold1" placeholder="gold" onkeyup="calc1()">
<input id="dps1" placeholder="dps" onkeyup="calc1()">
<input id="res1" onkeyup="calc1()">
```

Comment: Так, зачем событие отпускания клавиши на инпуте, в который Вы собираетесь записывать результат?

Comment: Результат умножения выводится замечательно

Comment: Понятно, кое-кто исправил вопрос до рабочего состояния, теперь он бесполезен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ от [НикитаГордеев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236895/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2)

```
<input id="gold1" placeholder="gold" onkeyup="calc1()">
<input id="dps1" placeholder="dps" onkeyup="calc1()">
<input id="res1" onkeyup="calc1()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Исправьте

> document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = res1;

на

```
document.getElementById("res1").value = res1;
```

и все заработает

Comment: Я изменил в вопросе, в сниппете не работает...

Comment: @Tarasovych а кто будет вызывать Вашу функцию, Пушкин? Добавьте `<button type="button" onclick="calc1()">Click</button>`

Comment: @Igor спасибо. А как сделать, чтобы значение появлялось без нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: @Tarasovych `<input onkeyup="calc1()" ...`

Comment: Работает, но нужно нажать enter при активном input, чтобы получить результат. А чтобы результат появлялся, когда заполнены два input'а для ввода - нужен if?

Comment: @Tarasovych Да, нужен `if` :)

Comment: @Tarasovych добавь `onkeyup="calc1()"` на оба поля для ввода, тогда не придется ентер жать и если одно из полей не будет заполнено - в третьем будет выведено `NaN` (Not-a-Number)

Comment: @НикитаГордеев спасибо!

Comment: А можно эту же функцию использовать для двух таких блоков с input'ами?

Comment: @Tarasovych можно. Примите, пожалуйста, ответ, который Вам помог (галка слева от ответа), и задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @Tarasovych да, одну функцию можно использовать где угодно сколько угодно раз.

Comment: @Igor ответ был дан в качестве комментария